# How to decode Unicode string in Tensorflow's graph pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I have created a tfRecord file to store data. I have to store Hindi text so, I have saved it in the bytes using string.encode('utf-8').

But, I am stuck at the time of reading the data. I am reading data with help of tensorflow dataset APIs. I know that i can decode it using string.decode('utf-8'), but this is not what I am looking for. I want some solution through which i can decode my byte string back to Unicode string inside graph only.

I have tried [as_text](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/as_text), [decoding_raw](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_raw) but they are giving error.

My parse(map) function:

```
def _parse_function(tfrecord_serialized):
    features={'float': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], 
    tf.float32,allow_missing=True),
         'byte': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
          'int': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], 
    tf.int64,allow_missing=True)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(tfrecord_serialized, 
    features)
    return parsed_features['float'],parsed_features['byte'], parsed_features['int']`
```

I am reading my tfRecord file as follows.

```
    filenames = ["data.tfrecord"] ## List of filename,Multiple filename can be provided together.
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()`

    t1,t2,t3 = iterator.get_next()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    a,b,c = sess.run([t1,t2,t3])
    print(a,b,c)
    b.decode('utf-8')`
```

On b.decode I am getting output perfectly fine, I wish to do it inside in the graph for the obvious reason, coming back from tf to python and going back again is generally is not a good idea.

Comment: Could you provide an example, including the code you have tried so far?

Comment: I have added code example. I have tried raw_decide and as_text on t3

Comment: are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python 3.

Comment: The problem is, unlike Python, TensorFlow does not have a data type supporting unicode, as in "a sequence of unicode code points" (like `str` in Python 3), but only `tf.string` which is just "a sequence of bytes" (like `bytes` in Python 3). I am not sure what exactly is your use case, but if you need decoding you will probably have to do it in Python, as a pre/post-processing step or with `tf.py_func`...

Comment: @jdehesa I need the text in the original language. so that later I can generate sparse tensor to pass it to CTC_LOSS. Later I figured out that out that I do not need to pass the text, I can pass encoded(character -> no) sequence in tfrecord and take there sparse tensor which for me will work perfectly fine. BTW, thanks for tf.py_func, I will definitely try that out.

Comment: They are coming with the Unicode support in the tensorflow. They have announced it in the developer summit.

Comment: One thing I have particularly found helpful is that encoding text in some particular standard format such as numbers, It can be helpful.