# How can I convert bytes to string In Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a list of bytes and I want to convert it to a list of strings, in python I use this decode function:

```
x=[b'\xd8\xa8\xd9\x85\xd8\xb3\xd8\xa3\xd9\x84\xd8\xa9',
    b'\xd8\xa5\xd9\x86\xd8\xb4\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa1',
    b'\xd9\x82\xd8\xb6\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa1',
    b'\xd8\xac\xd9\x86\xd8\xa7\xd8\xa6\xd9\x8a',
    b'\xd8\xaf\xd9\x88\xd9\x84\xd9\x8a'] 
y=[ a.decode("utf-8") for a in x]
```

How can I get the same result in Tensorflow?

thank you

Comment: There is not anything comparable in TensorFlow, for the simple reason that, in TensorFlow, the data type `tf.string` is equivalent to `bytes` from Python 3 (`str` from Python 2), and there is no data type unicode data, like `str` in Python 3 (`unicode` in Python 2), so there can be no concept of "decoding". Related: [How to decode Unicode string in Tensorflow's graph pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52578654), [Tensorflow batch: keep result as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53278261).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tf.compat.as_str_any()`.

```
for i in x:
    print(tf.compat.as_str_any(i))
```

will print list items as python strings. No need  to use session.